# Auto Layout and xib hybrid use is Invalid

Tags: ios, autolayout, xib

I'm use xib to create a tableView;
and to view controller like this :

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{

     _tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint

                              constraintWithItem:self.tableView

                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom

                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual

                              toItem:self.view

                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom

                              multiplier:1

                              constant:-100]];
}
```

the coding is Invalid.

but when use coding to create a table is valid.

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    [self.view addSubview:self.myTableView];

    _myTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;


    //布局tableView
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint

                              constraintWithItem:_myTableView

                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom

                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual

                              toItem:self.view

                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom

                              multiplier:1

                              constant:-100]];

}
```

why is that? how can hybrid auto layout in xib and coding?

Comment: What do you mean the coding is invalid? How do you know it is invalid?

Comment: use mobile debug， the coding is invalid when hybrid auto layout in xib and coding,and any use coding is ok.